# How to install TinyTex from .zip file? (install_windows_zip not working)

Tags: r, tinytex

I'm trying to install Tinytex from .zip file, as I'm unable to install TinyTex in the standard way (`install_tinytex`) due to some restrictions from my IT department.

The [advised](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/130) way to do so is `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()`. However, I get an error message, saying that object 'install_windows_zip' is not found.

So I would be glad for a kind advice on whether I miss out something with `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()` or there is another way to install TinyTex?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As tinytex:::install_windows_zip seems to have been removed from the package is there any other option for an offline installation? I am running into the same problem and have the same restrictions regarding my IT department.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tinytex:::install_prebuilt() on the file you have to download from https://github.com/yihui/tinytex-releases/releases.

Worked for me (see also https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/312)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem through the following steps:

1. After downloading the zip file, unzip the zip file and transfer it to your APPDATA folder, specifically the Roaming folder.
2. Create a .bat file and add the following code:

```
echo add tlmgr to PATH
cd /d "%APPDATA%\TinyTeX\bin\win32"
call tlmgr path add
if /i not "%CI%"=="true" call tlmgr option repository ctan
call tlmgr postaction install script xetex

exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

3. Run the .bat file as administrator
4. After this open RStudio and knit a .Rmd file to PDF to see if it worked for you.

I got the idea for this by reading the code in a .bat file I downloaded from https://yihui.org/tinytex/ specifically, this https://yihui.org/tinytex/install-bin-windows.bat

Answer (score -1):

The instructions on that GitHub issue page say that you need to call a function `install_windows_zip()` from package `tinytex`. Notice that that statement ends in `()`, so `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()`.

Comment: Hi Roman! Thank you for your answer! I was imprecise in my question, but I actually run `tinytex:::install_windows_zip()`. I'll correct this in my post.

Comment: The function may have been removed from the package. Technically you could flip through the changes of the install.R file on GitHub to test this theory.